# Should variables always be initialized with literals?

Tags: c

```
main()
{
    int a = 5, b = a, sum;
    sum = a + b;
    printf("sum is %d",sum);
}
```

In this C Program, will variable `b` be initialized at compile time or at run time?
Is it compile time initialization?
(C language)

Comment: don't think you've provided enough info. If `a` and `b` are never used from now on, they will probably get optimized out and won't exist at all. Otherwise, I would expect the assembly to initialize 2 memory locations/registers with 5 and go from there. Sooo, at compile time and runtime .. ?

Comment: Please [edit] your code, it is not compilable as is. Also you may want to upgrade to a [mcve], because without more context, the shown code could be global or within a function and that might influence the answer. Not saying it does, I am not sure without research, but you need to make things clearer to get good answers.

Comment: Please improve the terminology, "compile time initialisation" is not a thing. And you need to be clearer about what you mean by "get its value at compile time or at run time". Consider referring to more stages of the programs life time, e.g. link time, load time, ... And still, an MCVE would help to clarify the chronology of the context.

Comment: If you're talking about a particular compiler, look at the generated code. If you're talking about C in general, you need to explain what you mean by "compile time initialization" and what difference it would make.

Comment: You should also note that there is a thing called compiler optimization and so, your code is probably going to be optimized

Comment: To answer the original question: should variables always be initialized with "literals": **of course not, why else would there exist the entire construct of initializing them with non-literals**.

Comment: Write the code that is most readable and most logic. There will most likely be no performance difference

Answer (score 2):

No, variables should not always be initialised with literals, although some folk like to insure that variables are initialised at the point of declaration (and some firms insist on it) in order to avoid the reading of uninitialised variables in poorly crafted code.

As for any run-time behaviour: the *as-if* rule applies. Your source code merely describes what you want the behaviour to be, not the machine code that will be generated. Your variables will probably not exist in the compiled binary, which will be equivalent to

```
int main()
{
    printf("sum is %d", 10);
}
```

(The expression `int a = 5, b = a` is well-defined since `,` is a sequencing point, so `a` is initialised at the time its value is read to assign to `b`.)

Answer (score 1):

depends on whether the compiler/interpreter implemented the algorithm of [constant propagation](https://compileroptimizations.com/category/constant_propagation.htm) or not.

C standard does not impose not to use constant propagation. If one detects that that variable is not mutated it can be replaced with the precomputed value.  The [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule) says that one can do whatever optimization we want as time as the result is the expected one.